# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/Column

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I am new to Scala and Intellij and have been struggling with the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/Column
```

I built my scala/sbt project with the dependency:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % "2.2.0" % "provided"
```

And I was able to add the following import:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, SparkSession, Column}
```

However, the `Row` and `SparkSession` look normal, but `Column` appears to be gray-out.

I can't seem to figure out why `Column` is working differently.

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: If it is grayed out it just means your program is not requiring the import. Try `Code > Optimize Imports` in Intellij.

Comment: Could you share your code?

Comment: Thank you, Sebastian, for the clarification. However, I am still at a loss as to why I am getting this error, since my code does not require it.

Comment: What would happen if you remove %provided and refresh?

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting a similar error in my maven project, which I found was due to 
provided value in `<scope>` tag in my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

this provided did not allow my spark-SQL dependency to get resolved and hence I was getting the above-mentioned error, once I commented the provided part the spark_sql dependency was resolved and so was this error....You'll need to figure out why your dependency ain't getting resolved in sbt because that was the reason for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am also new in Scala. Resolved the same error by removing `provided`. But I got another error and was needed to add

```
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
 case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
 case x => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

to the sbt file.